# Adding Users to an Event via SQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function

I have a webpage that allows user to register their attendance to an event. This works fine however I am trying to add that a user cannot register for the same event more than once. So I am using a select statement to check if a record exists that matches the users input email and desired event. If a record exists it returns a value of 1 or greater and as a result informs the user they are already registered. However my code is returning a value of 1 no matter what email or event is selected. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 $sql2= "SELECT COUNT*
    FROM event_attendees
    WHERE event_name='$reg' AND user_email='$email'";
$r=mysql_query($sql2,$conn)or die(mysql_error());
if($r=1)
    {
        echo"Already Registered for this event";
        echo $r;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of problems:

1. The proper syntax for MySQL would be `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM...`.
2. In your conditional statement you have `if($r=1)` - that's assigning the value of 1 to `$r`. You need `if($r==1)`.
3. `mysql_query` returns a resource, not the count that you expect. You'll need to do a little more work to get the count from the response.

Comment: Also, you're using deprecated code to query MySQL. Use PDO or mysqli instead.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `if($r==1)` instead of `if($r=1)`

You are doing an assignment instead of comparison. Change that and your code will work as expected.

---

This(`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used. Switching to `PreparedStatements` is even more better to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

Answer (score 0):

USE FOLLOWING

```
if((int)$r === 1)
{

}
```

= means confer 
== means equal 
=== means equal and types are same